# How to display alert box in login screen in php. if a user enter's a wrong password or username for this code

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to display alert box in login screen in php.

if a user enter's a wrong password or username for this code

```
if(isset( $_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];

    include ("../backend/user.php");
    $c = new customer();
    //Assign username & password from post method to a varibale
    $res = $c->customer_login($email,$cpassword);
    if($res == true){
      //Direct the user to appropriate page 
      header("location:../views/profile.php");
    }else{

      include ("../backend/admin.php");
      $a = new admin();
      //Assign username & password from post method to a varibale
      $res = $a->admin_login($email,$cpassword);
      if($res == true){
        //Direct the user to appropriate page 
        header("location:../views/admin.php");
      }
    }
    //Display message invalid user name or password
    $message = "invalid username or password";
  }
```

Comment: php runs on the server - you can't alert on the server (php doesn't have an alert function anyway) and expect a client to see an alert in their browser

Comment: Yes, you can by injecting javascript code inside php

Comment: Check LOGIN PHP AJAX for examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Javascript:

> $message = "invalid username or password";

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>"
```